# Change dropdown button to radio buttons

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, radio-button, rate

I created a rating system. I used a dropdown button to choose from 1-10 to rate. I'd like to change this dropdown button to radio button instead to make it easier for viewers to rate. Can you help me? Here's my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Rate error solutions </title>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>
<div align="right">
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
<div align="center">

<img src="590px-HGST_CompanyLogo.svg.png" alt="Home" style="width:300;height:100"></div>
<br><br><br>
<center><b><font size="5"> RATE</font><br><br>
Note:</b> 10 = highest, 1 = lowest  </center><br>
<hr width='40%'>
<br>
</body>
</html>

<center>

<?php
    mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Can't connect to server.");
    mysql_select_db ("ojt") or die ("Can't connect to database.");

    $find_data = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM search");


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_data))
    {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $error = $row['error'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        $current_rating = $row['rating'];
        $hits = $row['hits'];


        echo "
            <form action='rate.php' method='POST'>
                <b>Error title: <u>$title</u> </b><br>
                Rate error solution: <select name = 'rating'>

                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>

                </select>
                <input type='hidden' value='$error' name='error'><br>
                <input type='submit' value='Rate!'><br><br>Current rating: "; echo round($current_rating,4); echo "


            <br><br></form><hr width='30%'><br>
        ";
        }




?>
</center>
```

Comment: Use a range slider it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: so you want to change a dropdown to a radio group, but you don't attempt any code, just post here for us to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for:

[WORKING:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8v4e0odw/4/)

**HTML**

```
<select name='rating'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>

<p id="rdb"></p>
```

**JS**

```
var num = $("option").length; /*Check num of Option Tags*/
$("select").hide(); /* Remove this and you will find Select box */
for(var i=1; i<=num; i++)
{
    var nums = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
    var ptag = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];    
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    var cellText = document.createTextNode(" " + nums[i] + " ");
    var label = parseInt(i);
    ptag.appendChild(cellText);
    ptag.appendChild(input);
}
```

Your HTML file must look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select name='rating'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
<p id="rdb"></p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var num = $("option").length; /*Check num of Option Tags*/
$("select").hide(); /* Remove this and you will find Select box */
for(var i=1; i<=num; i++)
{
    var nums = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
    var ptag = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];    
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    var cellText = document.createTextNode(" " + nums[i] + " ");
    var label = parseInt(i);
    ptag.appendChild(cellText);
    ptag.appendChild(input);
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello! thank you for your response. however, I do not know where to put the JS. I am really sorry; I have no background whatsoever in programming and I am given a project about PHP. where do I place the JS in my code? thank you'!

Comment: @Alnira Mei Causing, I have updated the answer above. Check it now.

Comment: hello! i'm sorry but there are a lot of 'undefined's. i'm not sure if it's me or not. i'm sorry, i really don't know how to make this work. it kind of looks like the one i'll be commenting below @divy3993

Comment: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined  undefined

Comment: Why have you posted your php code outside the body and html tags, place code between center tags along with center tag inside body of your file. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tqhctjsf/)

Comment: that's what i did the first time i tried the code. but i had the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

@divy3993

Here's what I did. i'm really sorry if i don't get it and thanks for giving me your time:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<title> Rate error solutions </title>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>
<div align="right">
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
<div align="center">

<img src="590px-HGST_CompanyLogo.svg.png" alt="Home" style="width:300;height:100"></div>
<br><br><br>
<center><b><font size="5"> RATE</font><br><br>
Note:</b> 10 = highest, 1 = lowest  </center><br>
<hr width='40%'>
<br>
</body>
</html>

<center>

<?php
    mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Can't connect to server.");
    mysql_select_db ("ojt") or die ("Can't connect to database.");

    $find_data = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM search");


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_data))
    {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $error = $row['error'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        $current_rating = $row['rating'];
        $hits = $row['hits'];


        echo "
            <form action='rate.php' method='POST'>
                <b>Error title: <u>$title</u> </b><br>
                Rate error solution: <select name = 'rating'>

                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>

                </select>

                <p id='rdb'></p>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                var num = $('option').length;
                $('select').hide(); 
                for(var i=1; i<=num; i++)
                {
                    var nums = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
                    var ptag = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];    
                    var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
                    input.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode('' + nums[i] + '');
                    var label = parseInt(i);
                    ptag.appendChild(cellText);
                    ptag.appendChild(input);
                }
                });
                </script>
                <input type='hidden' value='$error' name='error'><br>
                <input type='submit' value='Rate!'><br><br>Current rating: "; echo round($current_rating,4); echo "


            <br><br></form><hr width='30%'><br>
        ";
        }




?>
</center>
```